# Selenium Automation(.net) using Flash

Tags: c#, .net

I have a login page made of flash. How could I locate the objects(find the text box fields) so that I can automate the task in selenium?

Please could any one help. I am using .net for automating.

Answer (score 0):

Flash does not expose its document model like HTML does. However, you can use the ExternalInterface API to send messages to the Flash object and get responses back. Active Tuts has a brief primer on ExternalInterface at http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/flash-html-javascript-externalinterface/

Alternatively, you can use the FlashVars mechanism to send variables into the Flash object. This is one-way communication from the container into Flash.